# Building Stats with jqPlot

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, statistics, jqplot

is it possible to build stats like the image after does show?

I have try so mutch but doesn't work ... maybe someone can help me with this problem?

The jqPlot website is http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotOptions-txt.html .... or i have any a good how-two for an other "script" please let me know it ...

Regards

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To solve this one you need to use in combination bar renderer and the 'default' line renderer.
How it can be achieved I have already presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10735698/613495).