# combined line and bar w/ jqplot

Tags: jqplot

Is it possible w/ jqplot to display a line chart that 'overlays' a bar chart?

I have added a series to a stacked barchart and changed the renderer to $.jqplot.LineRender. This displays as a line but it is getting added to the stacked amounts.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes it can be done with `jqPlot`.

A sample showing how a bar chart can be presented on a single plot together with a line chart [is presented here, see the 3rd plot from the top](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/rotated-tick-labels.html).

[Here I made a sample to show line and stacked bar charts on a single plot.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/ZbHsD/)

Comment: The jqplot site example looks like what I want to do. Thanks! I might be wrong but your example appears to have the 'issue' I was talking about where the line chart is being added

Comment: Yea you are right it appears to be getting added to the previous series therefore you might be successful to combine it with the approach `jqPlot` guys give in the 3rd plot in the example. I guess that if it is a very annoying issue you can always try setting the values of the line accordingly to negative values that would move it to the wanted position. I will experiment with it tomorrow. Also (+1) for interesting question.

Comment: I found a nicer solution. You can disable stacking of a series by setting `disableStack : true` for it. Now it is also added to the code sample.

Comment: IMHO, that example is a better solution for what I am doing as the bar and line chart use the same yaxis. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks!! I was going crazy creating that type of chart myself.

Comment: Awesome. +1 for the example.

Answer (score 4):

I add [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/uWdbJ/) on jsFiddle, i hope this could be useful to you. It also shows the possibility to draw delimiting lines and areas for a better representation.

[image]

there is an article about this topic at this page: http://www.meccanismocomplesso.org/en/mean-mode-median-barchart/

```
.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 series:[
              {
                    color:'#0070c0',
                    label : 'Barchart',
                    renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                    rendererOptions: {
                          barPadding: 0,
                          barMargin: 0
                    },
                    pointLabels: { show: true }
              },
       {
                    yaxis: 'y2axis',
                    color: '#ff0000',
                    label : 'Line chart ',
                    renderer:$.jqplot.LineRenderer,
                    rendererOptions: {
                          barPadding: 0,
                          barMargin: 0
                    }
              }
        ]
```

It will draw both line and bar chart