# jqPlot combining a bubble plot and a line plot

Tags: plot, jqplot

Is it possible to **combine a bubble-plot and a line-plot** in the same chart using jqPlot ?

Based on the discussion in [combined line and bar w/ jqplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727285/combined-line-and-bar-w-jqplot) , I have created a jsfiddle which contains a buble-plot and a bar-plot here : http://jsfiddle.net/85K6K/6/

I am unable to convert the bar plot into line plot. How to do this ?

I tried (changing, removing) the renderer but the plot goes hayway

this is how I setup the series :

```
var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart', [ p, arr], {
    series: [
        {

                    renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                    rendererOptions: {
                        barMargin: 10
                    },
                    pointLabels: {
                        show: true,
                    }
                   //showMarker:false

        },
        {
                renderer: $.jqplot.BubbleRenderer,
                rendererOptions: {
                             bubbleAlpha: 0.6,
                             highlightAlpha: 0.8
                        },
                shadow: true,
                shadowAlpha: 0.05
        }],
    axesDefaults: {
        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
        },
        yaxis: {
            autoscale: true
        }
    }
});
```

What am I missing

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: I have a similar issue- I want to render a histogram as a bar-chart, and then overlay a standard distribution curve that aligns with the mean (so, a bezier curve). Thus far, no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By trial and error, I found that you need to set the `forceTickAt0` property to **true** for the y axis.

http://jsfiddle.net/85K6K/14/

Here's the relevant part :

```
yaxis: {
    autoscale: true,
    renderer: $.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer,
    rendererOptions: {
        forceTickAt0: true
    }
}
```

I think you should [consider filing a bug](https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/issues/new). There are [other](https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/issue/663/replot-resetaxes-yaxis-cause-nan-in-y-axis) [issues](https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/issue/205/all-0-values-in-yaxis-ticks-causes-nan) open in their database about the Y Axis failing with a NaN error, which seem related ; but I think your issue is worth posting on its own. With this question and the JSFiddle, it should be sufficiently well documented for the devs to tackle :)

**EDIT** : I don't know enough about your graph's data to tell if it's relevant, but maybe you want to use the `sortMergedLabels` property of the CategoryAxisRenderer, to make your graph look [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/85K6K/15/) ?

```
rendererOptions: {
    sortMergedLabels: true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I viewed it on Mozilla and found that it works! (but this does not load on Chrome though)